# Hide/Remove input number arrows in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

I would like to hide/remove the input[type=number] up and down arrows displayed in all of the main desktop browsers.

The following CSS works in Firefox Mozilla, Safari and Chrome and I belive Internet Explorer, but not in Opera.

```
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

How would I be able to apply this effect to the Opera web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term `-webkit` defines that it'll be applicable for browsers which use webkit engine. Opera has been using its own engine Presto for quite sometime and has recently started progress towards using chromium engine.

For the CSS to be compatible in Opera, you'd need to use `-o` instead.

```
input::-o-outer-spin-button,
input::-o-inner-spin-button {
    -o-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

---

### EDIT

On further searching on Opera community, [this particular thread](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1422602&t=1371696030&page=1#comment12430342) seems to be exactly the same and quoting the reply from there:

> Opera does not support styling the shadow DOM at the moment, so you
>   can't.

Comment: @user1752759 Possible reason mentioned [here](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1422602&t=1371696030&page=1#comment12430342)